# Netbeans syntax highlighting for a custom language inserted in a C or Assembler file

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting

I am using NetBeans 8.1 to edit standard “.c” and “.s” files for use on an embedded system and I see default syntax highlighting respectively. However, in these files I also embed a custom language between known tokens whose syntax I’d like to also be highlighted.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this please? Can NetBeans do this out of the box or I would have to write something, perhaps a plugin?

A quick search of Google or the NetBeans website doesn't bring any relevant hits, just for recognising a custom language in its own right not in an embedded form.

Thanks in advance,

Ian

Comment: An interesting question. This old (2008) article titled [Quick Start: Creating Language Tools In NetBeans IDE](https://dzone.com/articles/quickstart-guide-language-supp) is a tutorial showing how to introduce support for a new language into NetBeans. It might provide some useful insights, and there's no need to write a plugin. But the tricky part in your case is the embedding of one language in the source of another. That's already being done in NetBeans, where a JSP file can have an embedded Java scriptlet which has appropriate syntax highlighting, but I have no idea how that is implemented.